# Microphone testing on using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Hello I am trying to write a script, similiar to speak activity using cypress, this imitates a user using google speech. anyone knows how to do it or is it possible? thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8517948). You are encouraged to make an attempt. If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.